# Generate a certificate throw exception keytool

Tags: android, security, cryptography, certificate

I tried to generate new keystore that will contain my certificate using following command:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias mybks -file c:/path/to/burp.crt -keystore ssl_pinning_certs_bk146.bks -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath c:/path/to/bcprov-jdk15on-154.jar -storepass spassword
```

Here I use:
burp.crt - it's mine certificate exported from burp suite proxy
ssl_pinning_certs_bk146.bks - It's certificate that is taken from android application

When I run this command to generate new certificate to android app, I have following error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: KeyStore integrity check failed.
java.io.IOException: KeyStore integrity check failed.
        at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad
(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:792)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)
```

Where is the problem, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Shouldn't you first create the keystore and *then* import the certificate to it?

Comment: As I correctly understood, I already have a keystore from android app: ssl_pinning_certs_bk146.bks
 Can you give an explain? 
@MaartenBodewes

Comment: Ah, OK, I didn't know that. Note that usually the integrity check is calculated using a secret key. That secret key is usually derived from the password. Therefore the error could simply indicate that the wrong password has been used. That may also be due to character-encoding differences by the way, in case non-ASCII characters are used.